# What's that feature of PHP with a section of html/text closed off with start/end functions?

Tags: php

What's that feature of PHP where you have, say a "start" bit of code, then some html or text that would normally send to the browser, then a bit of code to "end" it?

For example,

```
<? start_something(); ?>

<html>some html</html>

<? end_something(); ?>
```

Yes, this is a built-in feature of php and I am sure of it, but I cannot remember what it's called.

Comment: Are you thinking of output buffer?  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

buffer?

```
ob_start();

//do some code

ob_flush(); //sends current code to browser

//do something else

ob_end_flush(); //or ob_end_clean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is how many websites apply a common header and footer to their web pages. By separating them into separate files and including them in each page they can easily maintain a consistent look and feel to their website all while making maintaining it easy since they would only need to update one or two files to change the appearance of the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

[Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)?

```
<? ob_start(); ?>

<html>some html</html>

<? ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP documentation for [print()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

```
print <<<END
This uses the "here document" syntax to output
multiple lines with $variable interpolation. Note
that the here document terminator must appear on a
line with just a semicolon no extra whitespace!
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're asking about output buffering, as mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php